# Passing Multiple text/plain values in share intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am creating a notepad application in android. I have given a functionality to share individual note with other apps. 
I want the share function to share the title and content of the note. I can't seem to make it work.
Below is my java code for share intent.

**JAVA**

```
    String title=noteModel.getTitle();
    String content=noteModel.getContent();
    Intent intentShare = new Intent();
    intentShare.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,title);
    intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,content);            
    intentShare.setType("text/plain");
    context.startActivity(intentShare.createChooser(intentShare,"Send note to"));
```

Comment: what is the problem u r facing?

Comment: I am unable to pass two values. In the above code only "content" value gets displayed on the screen to be share but not "title".
I have tried using a different key - `EXTRA_SUBJECT` for title and `EXTRA_TEXT` for content, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to pass multiple strings with just one `EXTRA_TEXT`.
I wanted to pass two values, namely, title and content, So I stored the value of title in a string called "title" and the value of content in a string called "content".
Now, the trick ! I concatenated both the strings together and stored that concatenated string to a new string and passed that string into `EXTRA_TEXT`.

I am gonna share my correct code just to give a clear picture.

```
String title=noteModel.getTitle();
String content=noteModel.getContent();
String titleAndContent="Title: "+title+"\n Content: "+content;

Intent intentShare = new Intent();
intentShare.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intentShare.setType("text/plain");
intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,titleAndContent);

context.startActivity(intentShare);
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the same key for two Extra

```
    intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,title);
    intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,content);
```

You have to use a different key for every extra you pass. Change the content extra similar to below one.

```
intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CONTENT,content);
```

Comment: Error pops up saying "Cannot resolve symbol EXTRA_CONTENT" , I need to initialize it but I am not sure what value to give it

Comment: public static final String EXTRA_CONTENT = "intent.extra.content.text"

Comment: use the same key to get from extra. that's it.

Comment: `EXTRA_CONTENT` doesn't get displayed but `EXTRA_TEXT` does.

Comment: In your receiver end get it by getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_CONTENT);

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "receiver end". 
Where am I suppose to get the intent?

Comment: how you get your intent passed in another acitivty

Comment: I have received the intent in my other activity with this code `Intent intent=getIntent();
intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_CONTENT);`

If this is what you were asking me to do then it doesn't work, same problem persists, only EXTRA_TEXT gets displayed

Comment: check your content text has value

Comment: Yes I checked the value of both title and content with the help of debugger, they both have valid values.

Answer (score 0):

```
intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,title);
intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,content); ///ovewriting value
```

please use different key

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
intentShare.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
intentShare.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);
```